# Trouble with dual input validaton a C++ program

Tags: c++, if-statement, do-while

SO I'm trying to:

1. Do dual input validation inside a do while loop
2. Check to see if the move has been made yet and whether it is a logical input. (# 1-9)

I originally thought if else statement but im not sure how to use the else statement to get back to the start of the loop.

```
do
{
  cout << "Interesting move, What is your next choice?: ";
  cin >> play;
  Pused[1] = play;
  if(play != Pused[0] && play != cantuse[0] && play != cantuse[1] )
  {
    switch(play)
    {
      default:cout << "Your choice is incorrect\n\n";
      break;
    }   
  }
  else
  { }
}    
while(play != 1 && play != 2 && play != 3 && play != 4 && play != 5 && play != 6 && play != 7 && play != 8 && play != 9);
Dis_board(board);
```

Comment: please cut down your code to a bare minimum if you want people to read it

Answer (score 0):

use "continue" keyword to go back to start of the loop.

Comment: Its a Do while and the since it is  true that the num is 1-9 it exits....it does not check to see if 1-9 has already been inputed

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `else`. I think it is not required. Automatically your loop will be continued if conditions in `while` are satisfied.

Comment: It needs the else because the if is saying that if it hasnt already been entered them do the function, else..... i need that else to return to above the if statement.......or to the Do statement if that was possible...

Comment: If you want to do some operation in else then only else is required otherwie not required at all. If your play value is greter than 9 than you loop will continue otherwise it will come out. Further you can use while(!(play>9)) as a condition check rather writing big while loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, but you've got a few conditions to solve in this loop:

1. Ask the user for input
2. Check if the users input is valid (Between 1-9 and not been used before)
3. Exit the loop if we have a valid choice

So we need to record what moves have been done and also check that the user's input is within the valid choices, we can use a loop that exits only when a valid choice is chosen.

```
int choice;
bool used[9] = { false }; // Set all values to false
std::cout << "Interesting move, what is your next choice?: ";
do {
    std::cin >> choice;
    // Here we check if the choice is within the range we care about
    // and not used, note if the first condition isn't true then
    // the second condition won't be evaluated, so if choice is 11
    // we won't check used[10] because the && will short circuit, this
    // lets us avoid array out of bounds. We also need to
    // offset the choice by 1 for the array because arrays in C++
    // are indexed from 0 so used runs from used[0] to used[8]
    if((choice >= 1 && choice <= 9) && !used[choice - 1]) {
        // If we're here we have a valid choice, mark it as used
        // and leave the loop
        used[choice - 1] = true;
        break; // Exit the loop regardless of the while condition
    }

    // If we've made it here it means the above if failed and we have
    // an invalid choice. Restart the loop!
    std::cout << "\nInvalid choice! Input: ";
} while (true);
```